# need help to a make navbar like this

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need my vavbar to display to be like[image: navbar]

I could not find any options for this in Bootstrap documents.
is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below bootstrap code

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a href="#" class ="navbar-brand">Application Name</a>
    </div>
    <!-- menu items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **navbar-inverse** class to your nav to see a dark nav bar.

Here is code snippet

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/karthikdivi/pen/qXOwoL